# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis equivalent of Prefetch Policy

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I am tasked with migrating ActiveMQ v5.10.0 code to Artemis 2.6.0 with Camel 2.22.0 and running into a problem with Prefetch policy. What is the Artemis equivalent of the following code:

```
ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
prefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(0);
prefetchPolicy.setQueueBrowserPrefetch(0); 
connectionFactory.setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy);
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artemis supports OpenWire so I believe you should be able to keep using your old code.  However, if you want to change for whatever reason the equivalent property is `consumerWindowSize` and it can be set on the URL used to connect to the broker, e.g. `tcp://host:61616?consumerWindowSize=0`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I will keep in mind about being able to use existing ArctiveMQ code with Artemis.